# Can "project is lead by" be ever correct?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Knowing that Lead-led-led, I find this sentence wrong (from a book available on Google books):

> The project is lead by an alliance of three partners, comprising the
>   GI, the FIZ Karlsruhe (a provider of scientific online information
>   services) and Springer- Verlag..

Shouldn't there be "led by"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct. "led by" is always right in this case. "Led" is the past tense of "lead".

Answer (score 0):

When you're hit over the head, the instrument could be a “lead” (*Plumbum*) pipe.

But when it's a verb, “lead” is the present and “led” is the past tense.

The problem is that the past tense is pronounced in exactly the same way as the above-mentioned metal, so people confuse the two.  I think this is a typographic error and someone not checking.

> The project **was lead** by an alliance of three partners, comprising the GI, the FIZ Karlsruhe (a provider of scientific online information services) and Springer- Verlag..  [Past tense]

or

> The project **is led** by an alliance of three partners, comprising the GI, the FIZ Karlsruhe (a provider of scientific online information services) and Springer- Verlag.. [Present tense]

Would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Most definitely "led by" is grammatically correct and would always be used in speech and should always be used in writing. However, some people may mistakenly use "Lead" as a participle and past tense in casual writing (*e.g.*, texting) because "led" (the past tense and perfect participle of the verb "lead") is a homophone of the noun "lead." How common is the mistake of writing "lead" instead of "led" is impossible to say, but avoid it if you want to be thought skilled in English.

Comment: Please add references for both of your assertions.